# kafka jdbc sink connector: recreated all other connectors when create or update one connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have about 500 connectors, and every time I create a new one, I have to wait long time to recreate the previous. It is too slow.

The sink.properties is as follows

```
{
    "name": "saas-saas_order-worder_fee_price-sink",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
        "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "saasosvc-worder_fee_price",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "name": "saas-saas_order-worder_fee_price-sink",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
        "auto.create": "true",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/saas?user=postgresuser&password=postgrespw",
        "errors.log.enable": "true",
        "insert.mode": "upsert",
        "pk.mode": "record_value",
        "pk.fields": "id"
    }
}
```

some logs are as follows

```
> 2019-06-12 05:44:42,242 INFO   || 
> WorkerSourceTask{id=saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_furnituresaleservice-source-0}
> flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask]
>     2019-06-12 05:44:45,950 INFO   ||  WorkerSinkTask{id=saas-appconstruction-appconstruction_requestrecord-sink-0}
> Committing offsets asynchronously using sequence number 20376:
> {appssvc-appconstruction_requestrecord-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2340,
> leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,242 INFO   ||  Connector saas-saas_order-worder_fee_price-sink config updated  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,745 INFO   ||  Rebalance started   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,747 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-order_base-product_vs_install-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,747 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-dyrs_complainservice-complain_type_record-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,748 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-appcustomerself-appcustomerself_appversionuser-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,748 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_changeservice-replace_product-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,748 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_designservice-version_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,748 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-dyrs_settlementservice-source  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,748 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-appcustomerself-appcustomerself_advice-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,748 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-im-im_accesstoken-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,761 INFO   ||  172.31.206.219 - - [12/Jun/2019:05:45:18 +0000] "POST /connectors/ HTTP/1.1" 201 604  549
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,775 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-im-im_accesstoken-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,776 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-saas_order-dd_order-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,778 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-dyrs_settlementservice-source  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,780 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-dyrs_settlementservice-balance_info_detail-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,781 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_designservice-version_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,781 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-dyrs_authorityservice-pro_city_area-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,781 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-dyrs_complainservice-complain_type_record-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,781 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-constructionconfig-constructionconfig_checkmanagedetailstandard-sink
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,799 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-saas_order-dd_order-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,799 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-saas_order-goods-sink   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,857 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-saas_order-goods-sink   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,857 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_businessopportunityservice-business_process_operator-sink
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,860 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-appcustomerself-appcustomerself_appversionuser-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,860 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_changeservice-custom_wood_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,862 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-order_base-product_vs_install-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,863 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_quotelistservice-pre_quote_detail_tab_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,865 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_changeservice-replace_product-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,868 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_quoteservice-program_template_tab-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,870 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-dyrs_settlementservice-balance_info_detail-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,870 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-dyrs_settlementservice-balance_config-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,866 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-appcustomerself-appcustomerself_advice-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,873 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-dyrs_authorityservice-account_login_fail-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,872 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-dyrs_authorityservice-pro_city_area-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,873 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_dataexpansionservice-dynamic_tabpk-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,875 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-constructionconfig-constructionconfig_checkmanagedetailstandard-sink
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,875 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_promotionservice-offer_content-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,884 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_businessopportunityservice-business_process_operator-sink
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,885 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_businessopportunityservice-personal_clue_limit-sink
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,891 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_changeservice-custom_wood_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,891 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-dyrs_settlementservice-balance_operation-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,902 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_quotelistservice-pre_quote_detail_tab_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,902 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-order_base-unit_vs_unit-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,904 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_dataexpansionservice-dynamic_tabpk-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,905 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_quoteservice-program_template_tab-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,907 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_fieldassociationservice-source  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,904 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-dyrs_authorityservice-account_login_fail-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,907 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-customerself-customerself_msgsendrecorddetail-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,908 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-finereport-constructionprocess_constructioninfoprocesscheck-sink 
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:18,913 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-dyrs_settlementservice-balance_config-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,134 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-order_base-unit_vs_unit-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,136 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_furnituresaleservice-fur_sale_contract_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,139 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_businessopportunityservice-call_record-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,154 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_furnituresaleservice-fur_sale_contract_info-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,154 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_fieldassociationservice-pre_filed-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,166 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_promotionservice-offer_content-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,166 INFO   ||  Stopping connector saas-runmonitoring-runmonitoring_browsinghistory-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
>     2019-06-12 05:45:19,167 INFO   ||  Stopped connector saas-com_dyrs_mtsp_fieldassociationservice-pre_filed-sink  
> [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Stop the world" rebalances are a known issue with Kafka Connect. The good news is that with [KIP-415](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-415%3A+Incremental+Cooperative+Rebalancing+in+Kafka+Connect) which is due in Apache Kafka 2.3 there is a new incremental rebalance feature which should make things much better.

In the meantime the only other option is to partition your Kafka Connect workers and have separate clusters, splitting the 500 connectors up over them (e.g. by function, type, or other arbitrary factor).